# Exit code: 1 Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

Tags: yarnpkg, sharp, vips

[image]

I'm getting error while installing dependencies node_modules/sharp error. Please have a look at the picture.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "towni-staff",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js && cp public/firebase-messaging-sw.js dist/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "dev:hot": "npm run dev -- --hot",
    "docker:dev": "node docker/dev.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ./",
    "start": "node server/"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged && npm run test"
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://globalwebdev-towni@dev.azure.com/globalwebdev-towni/Towni%20-%20Admin/_git/Towni%20-%20Admin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
    "@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker": "^3.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.28",
    "dayjs-plugin-utc": "^0.1.2",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.6",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-static-gzip": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^7.16.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-date-picker": "^8.0.1",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.15",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.6.4",
    "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.10",
    "react-recaptcha-google": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-slideshow-image": "^1.3.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.4.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "@svgr/cli": "^4.3.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^4.3.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "favicons-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^3.0.9",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a globally installed libvips. Remove that, and sharp will download a precompiled version for your platform (also, please don't post screenshots ... just copy-paste the text and quote it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue following a software update to Big Sur 11.4.
If you're using a M1 Apple hardware, make sure livips is installed globally using Homebrew. This is necessary for Sharp to compile when using M1 chip. (I think the latest version of sharp now has binaries for M1 so might not be necessary with latest version).
Using homebrew, uninstall ilmbase. Make sure imath IS installed. If it's not, install it.
Run brew doctor - it may tell you that OpenEXR isn't linked. Link it.
This should fix it